# How to return a statement when the input is blank?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to get my code to return a statement when my input is blank. Here is my current code.

```
public boolean inputLastname(){
   System.out.println("Enter New Employee Information");
   System.out.print("Enter Employee Last Name: ");
   lastName = sc.next();

   if(lastName.trim().equals(" "))
       return false;
   return true;
}
```

I'd like it to say "No Employee Information Entered" and return false as well.
How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

Comment: use ``org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
public boolean inputLastname(){
   System.out.println("Enter New Employee Information");
   System.out.print("Enter Employee Last Name: ");
   lastName = sc.nextLine();

   Boolean returnBool = true;

   if(lastName.isEmpty()){
       returnBool = false;
       System.out.println("No Employee Information Entered");
       }
   return returnBool;
}
```

I think this is more straightforward just by testing whether or not the String is empty. This also makes it cleaner by only having one return statement.

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but it didn't do anything different. It still continues as normal.

Comment: @JohnnyB Hi sorry, I just edited the post. I changed sc.next() to sc.nextLine() and now it should work for you.

Comment: @JohnnyB no problem, glad to help. Just remember, you can help others viewing this post in the future by accepting an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After trim it can't have a space, so it should be "" ,

```
      public boolean inputLastname(){
               System.out.println("Enter New Employee Information");
               System.out.print("Enter Employee Last Name: ");
               lastName = sc.next();

               if(lastName.trim().equals("")){
    System.out.println("No Employee Information Entered");
                   return false;
                 }
               return true;
           }
```

Comment: Just tried this as well, and nothing different is happening.

Comment: @JohnnyB What is the output you got after running this code ?

Comment: Enter New Employee Information
Enter Employee Last Name:

and then when I hit enter nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I suggst you to add a StringBuffer or StringBuilder (And not String because it's immutable) as parameter for your method, and to put the appropriate text in it

**Edit :**
Sorry I have misread the question, @Benjamin Lawry's answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the problem is that System.out has no time to proceed output, so you can add System.out.flush() to make it print its buffer, like this:

```
public boolean inputLastName(){
    System.out.println("Enter New Employee Information");
    System.out.print("Enter Employee Last Name: ");
    lastName = sc.nextLine();

    if (lastName.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("No Employee Information Entered");
        System.out.flush();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```